# How to hide a taskbar entry but keep the window form?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

I'd like to hide the taskbar entry to maximize effective space since the app has a systray icon, i dont need the taskbar entry. The app doesnt allow you to only have a systray instead of both.

How can I hide a taskbar entry but keep the window form?

Comment: For what framework? Some provide a property for this (C# windows forms has a ShowInTaskbar property on the Form object)

Comment: ShowInTaskbar came to mind first time I read the question. Then I realized it might not be a programming question. Anyway, +1

Comment: This is not programming related. The OP just wants to hide the taskbar entry of a generic program, not a self-written one. http://superuser.com/questions/54284/how-to-hide-a-taskbar-entry-but-keep-the-window-form

Comment: for windows application which is able to do this see:

http://superuser.com/questions/54284/how-to-hide-a-taskbar-entry-but-keep-the-window-form/341455#341455

Comment: I was having the same issue except for I wanted to do so in my code. Tnx to u guys esp  @rslite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In what language is your application written?

The API call you want is called [SetWindowLong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Example Delphi code would be:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);

  SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
          GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);

  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_SHOW);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Following is for MSVC:

```
if (bShow)
    ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
else
    ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, 0);
```

ModifyStyleEx documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf6zed6%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Links:

- [How To Hide A Window in TaskBar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/hidetaskbar.aspx).
- [How to dynamically show/hide the Taskbar application button](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/frameworks/advancedui/article.php/c3227/).

Comment: Oops, i didn't mean programming code but an actual program. Thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. If you are searching for a handy tool, ask the same question on superuser.com. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

## .NET

Solution for C# would be:

```
ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Solution for VB.NET would be:

```
ShowInTaskbar = False
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also read the comments  before posting? rslite had already answered for .Net

Comment: @tzup: rslite should have made his comment an answer. @awe: it might help to mention that `ShowInTaskbar` is a `Form` method.