# wxTaskBarIcon sample

Tags: wxwidgets

I have successfully built wxWidgets, 2.9.4 and the samples on Mac OS X, xubuntu and WinXP. Running the taskbar sample on all three platforms, there is an icon on the task bar but also an icon showing a running application. This is not normal task bar app behavior, right?

Answer (score 2):

It is normal taskbar behavior. wxTaskBarIcon adds the icon to the system tray. on Windows the application's icon in taskbar is controlled by other API.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553923/how-to-hide-a-taskbar-entry-but-keep-the-window-form) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/vcgeneral/thread/2d2ef9ad-487b-43d2-997b-e0c2540064d6).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gave me new ideas on what to search for. What I was looking for was wxFRAME_NO_TASKBAR. Adding this flag to my frame creation gives me the behavior I want on Linux/xfce. However it appears to not be working on Mac Cocoa.

Comment: This behaviour is platofrm-specific. Just google for appropriate solution for Mac like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620841/how-to-hide-the-dock-icon.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now. Yep adding `<key>LSUIElement</key><true/>` to the Info.plist.in file did the trick - Thanks again. And for those that may find this thread, creating the main frame with  `wxCAPTION| wxSIMPLE_BORDER| wxSYSTEM_MENU| wxCLOSE_BOX| wxFRAME_NO_TASKBAR| wxSTAY_ON_TOP` and using the TaskBarIcon class per the taskbar sample, it "just works" on xfce(linux) and WinXP.